# Perplexing Gaps and Island ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql

I need to re-order the following data into their own islands in Oracle SQL by TSK and ACTCODE, and ordered by dates. The new data will display TSK, STARTDATE of the first instance of a continuous group, ENDDATE of the last instance of a continuous group, with the rest of the data fields all pertaining to the last instance (MAX ENDDATE) of a continuous group. Is there a way to do this outside of a stored procedure?

Thank you for your help!

example data set:

(DATA BEFORE)

```
   (Fields) TSK STARTDATE  ENDDATE    ACTCODE    DPTCODE   TSKCODE   OPERID
    1       A   01/06/2014 01/06/2014 2          1587      1584      I511191
    2       A   01/06/2014 01/06/2014 11         1587      1583      I511191
    3       A   01/08/2014 01/08/2014 2          1587      1584      CLARKC
    4       A   01/16/2014 01/16/2014 2          1587      1585      MENDUA
```

(DATA AFTER)

```
   (Fields) TSK STARTDATE  ENDDATE    ACTCODE    DPTCODE   TSKCODE   OPERID
    1       A   01/06/2014 01/06/2014 2          1587      1584      I511191
    2       A   01/06/2014 01/06/2014 11         1587      1583      I511191
    3       A   01/08/2014 01/16/2014 2          1587      1585      MENDUA
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "reorder"?  Table records(normally) are not stored in any specific order.

Comment: I meant reorder by the dates, tsk, and actcode

Answer (score 3):

The basic "gap-and-islands" procedure is to identify the groups by taking the difference between two sequential values.  In your case, you can do this to identify the groups:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by fields) -
        row_number() over (partition by tsk, actcode order by fields)
       ) as grp
from table t
```

To get what you want is just a bit more work and an aggregation:

```
select min(fields) as fields, min(startdate) as startdate, tsk, max(enddate) as enddate, actcode,
       max(DPTCODE) keep (dense_rank first order by enddate desc),
       max(TSKCODE) keep (dense_rank first order by enddate desc),
       max(OPERID) keep (dense_rank first order by enddate desc)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by fields) -
              row_number() over (partition by tsk, actcode order by fields)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, tsk, actcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle? If it's a recent one there will be support for OLAP functions (a bit simplified):

```
select min(startdate) as startdate
     , max(enddate) as enddate
     , actcode
     , grp
from (
    select startdate, enddate, actcode
         , row_number() over (order by startdate)
         - row_number() over (partition by actcode
                              order by startdate) as grp
    from T
) as A
group by actcode, grp
```

Comment: Hi Lennart, it's Oracle 10.5.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon for your response!  I think I was missing the dense rank formula all along.  In any case, works perfectly with my program.  Thanks so much everyone for all your help.

```
with testsomething as (      
select distinct tskid,pidate,operid,starttime,to_date(substr(effdate,5,2)||'/'||substr(effdate,7,2)||'/'||substr(effdate,1,4),'MM/DD/YYYY') as serveffdate,to_date(substr(pidate,5,2)||'/'||substr(pidate,7,2)||'/'||substr(pidate,1,4)||' '||
substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),1,2)||':'||substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),3,2)||':'
||substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),5,2), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  as startdatetime,
to_date(substr(pidate,5,2)||'/'||substr(pidate,7,2)||'/'||substr(pidate,1,4)||' '||
substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),1,2)||':'||substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),3,2)||':'
||substr(lpad(starttime,8,0),5,2), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as enddatetime,
endtime, dptcode,actcode,tskcode from tskhist where tskid in (select tskid from comptsk where compdate between '20140501' and '20140530') and dptcode=1587
order by tskid,pidate, starttime asc)
--,lastoperid as
  --(select distinct tskid,actcode,operid,max(enddatetime) from testsomething group by tskid,operid,actcode)
  ,q AS
        (
        SELECT  tskid,dptcode,actcode,enddatetime,startdatetime,tskcode,serveffdate,operid,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tskid, actcode ORDER BY startdatetime) AS rnd,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tskid ORDER BY startdatetime) AS rn
        FROM  testsomething
)
,q2 as (
select min(startdatetime) as startdatetime,max(enddatetime) as enddatetime,tskid,actcode,dptcode,tskcode,serveffdate,max(OPERID) keep (dense_rank first order by enddatetime desc) as operid
from q
GROUP BY
        tskid,actcode,dptcode,tskcode,serveffdate,(rnd - rn) order by tskid,actcode,startdatetime)    


select distinct startdatetime, enddatetime,serveffdate,operid,a.tskid,a.actcode,(case when a.actcode=0 then 'NoAction' else b.actdesc end) as actdesc,a.dptcode,c.dptdesc,a.tskcode,d.tskdesc
from q2 a, acttype b, dpt c, tsktype d
where a.actcode=b.actcode(+) and a.dptcode=c.dptcode(+) and a.tskcode=d.tskcode(+) 
 order by tskid, actcode,startdatetime asc
```